# Different timing functions for different parts of css3 keyframe animation? (accurate bounce)

Tags: css, animation

Is this possible? I'm trying to recreate a ball dropping onto the screen, and I have an animation like this:

```
@keyframes bounce {
  20%, 40%, 60%, 74%, 84%, 92%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -100vh);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0, -40vh);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -20vh);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0, -10vh);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, -5vh);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(0, -2vh);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(0, -1vh);
  }
}
```

and this, when implemented like this:

```
.ball {
  animation: bounce 3s cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22) 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

produces something that looks like this:

[image: bounce!]

This is.. *okay*, but not ideal. I'd prefer to do something like:

[image: actual bounce]

But in order to do this I need to have a different timing function for the initial 0-> 20% compared to the rest of them. Is there a way to do different timing functions for different parts of a keyframe animation? Or perhaps a different way to get an accurate *bouncing* animation that I'm not thinking of? Any help would be appreciated!

**edit:** added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nfdp69pw/).

Comment: You can use the property [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) on each keyframe. This controls the function from the beginning to the end of the respective keyframe.

Comment: Yeah! But is there a way to use it on (for instance) 0% -> 20% of the keyframe instead of the whole thing? Like use 'ease-in' for 0% -> 20%, and then 'ease-out' for 20% -> 30%, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can specify the function for *each keyframe* instead of the entire animation - [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/nfdp69pw/1/)

Comment: that's just what i was looking for. thanks so much! i'll accept your answer if you wanna post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than specifying a [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) for the **entire animation**, you can specify for **each key frame**. The function represents how the the values are interpolated from the beginning to end of the respective key frame.

Here's an example by adding an `ease` function to the keyframes `20%, 40%, 60%, 74%, 84%, 92%, 100%`.

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  20%, 40%, 60%, 74%, 84%, 92%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    animation-timing-function: ease;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -100vh);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0, -40vh);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -20vh);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0, -10vh);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, -5vh);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(0, -2vh);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(0, -1vh);
  }
}

.ball {
  background: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: bounce 3s cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22) 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"> </div>
```